# How do I convert a list into image?

Tags: python

I have a data in very weird form:
[image of data in list format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YPS3n.png)

How would I convert this list into image?
I tried using PIL but it didn't work:

```
array = np.array(aList, dtype=np.uint8)
image = Image.fromarray(array)
image.save('output.png')
```

I got following error:

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PIL/Image.py in fromarray(obj, mode)
2648             typekey = (1, 1) + shape[2:], arr["typestr"]
-> 2649             mode, rawmode = _fromarray_typemap[typekey]
2650         except KeyError:

KeyError: ((1, 1, 256, 256, 3), '|u1')

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-39-c48b139b22e6> in <module>
  1 array = np.array(list_of_arrays, dtype=np.uint8)
  ----> 2 image = Image.fromarray(array)
  3 image.save('output.png')

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PIL/Image.py in fromarray(obj, mode)
2649             mode, rawmode = _fromarray_typemap[typekey]
2650         except KeyError:
-> 2651             raise TypeError("Cannot handle this data type")
2652     else:
2653         rawmode = mode

TypeError: Cannot handle this data type
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your array has the wrong shape. If you do:

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image


aList = [[[255, 255, 255],
           [255, 255, 255],
           [255, 255, 255]],

          [[255, 255, 255],
          [255, 255, 255],
          [255, 255, 255]],

         [[255, 255, 0],
         [255, 255, 0],
         [255, 255, 0]]]
array = np.array(aList, dtype=np.uint8)
image = Image.fromarray(array)
image.save('output.png')
```

It works fine. Since your data has the format:

```
[np.array([[[[]]]])]
```

you have to select:

```
array = np.array(aList[0][0], dtype=np.uint8)
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to reshape the array first.

```
image = image.reshape(image.shape[2:])
```

This takes away the first two unwanted dimensions.